# Unable to create session with grakn keyspace after idle for some time

Tags: vaticle-typedb

While trying to create a session to grakn keyspace,after the grakn server is idle for sometime, i am getting session error.

I am using a python 3.6 application which has grakn-client of version 1.6.0 and the grakn server version is 1.6.0. I am getting this error intermittently. Only after the grakn server is idle for some time and on the first try. Trying to connect again after this error, with create the sessionid.

Could not obtain sessionId for keyspace abc

Answer (score 0):

We have most commonly seen this error when using mismatched versions of client and server somehow - either running the wrong server version. Please double check your client and server versions, and follow the docs for importing the right paths. Also, to verify if the server is doing something wrong (ie. the suspicious "only after grakn server is idle for some time") - try to connect to the server using Grakn console to perform some operations.

Comment: As per grakn documentation (http://dev.grakn.ai/docs/client-api/python), for grakn core 1.6.0, they are suggesting python client 1.6.0. We are using the same. From grakn console this is fine. The issue is getting while using the python client.

Comment: This is quite interesting, and it appears you can reproduce the intermittent error pretty reliably? Please file an issue https://github.com/graknlabs/ and we'll resolve it as soon as possible!

Comment: Please find the error generated by python grakn-client .

<_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
details = “OS Error”
debug_error_string = “{“created”:”@1592293927.075671633",“description”:“Error received from peer”,“file”:“src/core/lib/surface/call.cc”,“file_line”:1017,“grpc_message”:“OS Error”,“grpc_status”:14}"

Also we are getting this error while trying to retrive all keyspace name list. client.keyspaces().retrieve() is also throwing this error intermittendly.